How did Rashi reach the number of eight people carrying the grapes?
The פסוק states:

וַיָּבֹ֜אוּ עַד־נַ֣חַל אֶשְׁכֹּ֗ל וַיִּכְרְת֨וּ מִשָּׁ֤ם זְמוֹרָה֙ וְאֶשְׁכּ֤וֹל עֲנָבִים֙ אֶחָ֔ד וַיִּשָּׂאֻ֥הוּ בַמּ֖וֹט בִּשְׁנָ֑יִם וּמִן־הָרִמֹּנִ֖ים
וּמִן־הַתְּאֵנִֽים׃ (במדבר יג:כג)

And they came to the brook of Eshkol, and they cut from there a branch and one cluster of grapes, and they carried it on a pole, by two, and of the pomegranates and of the figs. (Numbers 13:23) [Translation mine.]


רש''י explains (ד''ה וישאהו):

.מִמַּשְׁמַע שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וַיִּשָּׂאֻהוּ בַמּוֹט" אֵינִי יוֹדֵעַ שֶׁהוּא בִשְׁנַיִם? מַה תַּ"ל "בִּשְׁנָיִם"? בִּשְׁנֵי
מוֹטוֹת. הָא כֵיצַד? שְׁמוֹנָה נָטְלוּ אֶשְׁכּוֹל, אֶחָד נָטַל תְּאֵנָה וְאֶחָד רִמּוֹן

From the implication of that which has been said "And they carried it on a pole," don't I know that it is [carried] by two [people]? Why, then, did the verse say "by two"? [It means that it was carried] by two poles. How [was] this [done]? Eight took a cluster, one took a fig and one took a pomegranate. [Translation mine.]


If there were two poles, there must have been four people, because there were two people per pole. How then, does רש''י reach the number eight people?

Rashi points to Sotah 34 ....

Gur Aryeh has a breakdown of the reasoning. I think his point is that two poles side by side would essentially function as a wide board, so 4 people would still be carrying it as a single load. The posuk is trying to say the lift itself needed a lift, i.e. two poles to carry the cluster and another two poles to assist in carrying those poles.

All text and translation have been taken from Sefaria
Rashi is basing his comment on the Gmara in Sotah 34a which states:

אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק: טוּרְטָנֵי, וְטוּרְטָנֵי דְטוּרְטָנֵי, הָא
כֵּיצַד? שְׁמֹנָה נָשְׂאוּ אֶשְׁכֹּל, אֶחָד נָשָׂא רִימּוֹן, וְאֶחָד
נָשָׂא תְּאֵינָה. יְהוֹשֻׁעַ וְכָלֵב לֹא נָשְׂאוּ כְּלוּם.
Rabbi Yitzḥak said: They were configured like upper rods of scales
[turtanei] that are balanced on the lower rods of scales, i.e., there
were not two but four poles. How so? Eight of the spies carried the
cluster of grapes, one of them carried a pomegranate, and one carried
a fig. Joshua and Caleb did not carry anything.

And on this Rashi says:

אמר רבי יצחק טורטני וטורטני דטורטני - משאוי ומשאוי תחת משאוי שהתחתונים
מסייעין את העליונים ובכל אחד היו שני מוטות כיצד שני מוטות הולכין זה
אצל זה וארבעה נושאין אותם ושני מוטות אחרים וארבעה בני אדם נושאין אותם
והם באלכסון מתחת שנים העליונים מוט אחד לראש האחד ומוט אחד לראש השני
והולכין באלכסון ורבי יצחק לאו מקרא שמיע ליה אלא דפשיטא ליה דרימון
ותאינה סגי בשנים ויהושע וכלב לא נשאו כלום פשו להו תמניא לאשכול ואם לאו
מדרש הראשון המלמדנו דלאו מוט אחד קאמר קרא לא היינו יודעים לכוין שמנה
בני אדם למשאו אלא דשמעינן מיניה דשני מוטות היו ואתא רבי יצחק לאשמועינן
דשני משאות היו שם וכל אחד שני מוטות

Based on this understanding when the Pasuk says two poles it seemingly refers to the layer of poles as opposed to the poles themselves, so there were two layers of two poles I.e 4 poles in total. The easiest way to picture it is a grid of Tik-Tak-Toe. According to this view it is understandable why 8 people were needed. 2 poles directly supporting the grapes (4 people) and 2 poles perpendicular supporting the top poles (4 people)
